# In proving Splitting Lemma, why does Aluffi show $N \cong M \oplus \ker \psi$ instead of $N \cong M \oplus \mathrm{coker}\varphi$ like Hatcher?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, proof-explanation, exact-sequence

From *Algebra: Chapter $0$* by Aluffi:

> [image]

He proves this by showing $N \cong M \oplus \ker \psi$:

> [image]

However, as I read Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* this past semester, he has us show (in this case) $N \cong M \oplus \mathrm{coker} \varphi$:

> [image]
>   [image]

I managed to put together the maps used by Aluffi and by Hatcher to come up with the isomorphism $M \oplus \ker \psi \cong M \oplus \mathrm{coker} \varphi$.

However, as Hatcher's proof seemed more intuitive, **I was wondering why Aluffi chose to show $N \cong M \oplus \ker \psi$? It also doesn't seem like he is using $\mathrm{coker}\varphi$ in the proof, so I was extra puzzled.**

Comment: Odd to expect there to be a reason for this.  The theorem can be proved in two slightly different ways, so what?

Comment: Personal preference?

Comment: About the cokernel: If $0 \to M \to N \to L \to 0$ is exact, then $L \cong N / \ker(N \to L) = N / \operatorname{im}(M \to N) = \operatorname{coker}(M \to N)$. So since injectivity just means that the sequence $0 \to M \to N$ is exact, we can extend it to a short exact sequence using the cokernel, and hence talk about splitting.